# How to prompt user to turn on otg from app?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-settings, usb-otg

I am building an app that interacts with an external device connected via usb. But for some phones like realme, oppo the app does not know whether the device is connected if the otg is turned off. Is there a way to know whether otg is on and make my app prompt the user to turn on otg if otg was off?

Comment: What is otg...?

Comment: @blackapps See the usb-otg tag. USB OTG, the ability to act as USB master (instead of the regular USB client mode) and thus connect to USB devices like flash drives or other USB devices.